# Meaning of 'Would be'

Tags: subjunctives

How can I express the below Idea in a single sentence?

> Right now I have no driving license. Therefore I can't drive and I don't drive any vehicle. But I am thinking that, "if I had taken a driving license it was possible for me to drive vehicles"

So can I say it like this?

> If I had taken a driving license, I would be able to drive.

or like this?

> If I had a driving license, I could drive.

Comment: Well, "I would be able to drive" is correct.  But you don't "take a driving license".

Comment: So How do I say that? "If I had a driving license...". Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well you *can* drive without a driving license, just not legally.

You also would take a driving *test* to obtain a driving *license*. The phrase you would want would be your second suggestion of:

> If I had a driving license, I could drive.

You just need to be aware that having a license is more of a permission to drive, so maybe it would be better phrased as:

> If I had a driving license, I would be allowed to drive.

Or

> If I had a driving license, I could legally drive.

Comment: I'll note that in the US the idiomatic term is "driver's license".